# Blender Booleon affecting sculpting geometry

Tags: modifiers, sculpting, geometry, artifacts

I am following a tutorial made by Grantt Abbitt and I added a Boolean to my axe head and when I enter sculpting mode after applying the Boolean I get really weird object shading. Ive tried different objects and they all cause the goemoetry to shade weird. Ive attached photos of the geometry shading and wireframe geometry before the Boolean.[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is your model *Shaded Smooth*? (https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/100221/107598) and have you Auto Smooth enabled? Auto Smooth doesn't work in Sculpt mode. If yes, switch the shading to *Shaded Flat* -- or just do the remesh operation. The result will be the same.

Comment: I had smooth shading on! Thank you so much!